# Sysfs for the SPI device

Tags: linux

How can I use the sysfs to detect if my hardware module(e.g. MSR) execute an event or an interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague.
For an interrupt, you can look at the output of `cat /proc/interrupts` and see if the interrupt count for your driver is increasing.

sysfs is here to show you attribute of your device or driver. If you want to trace the execution of driver code, look at the source code. There might be debug printk, that are only enabled if you load your driver with some command line parameter. For instance :

```
rmmod mymodule
modprobe mymodule debug=1
```

Debug message usually appear on the console, and you can also see them with the `dmesg` comand

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to export the information of whether hardware module(e.g. MSR) executes an event or an interrupt or not, here is the answer:

you can create a device attribute using sysfs api like:

```
static numbers;  
/* suppose numbers may be increased in your event function */
static DEVICE_ATTR(event_numbers, 0400, event_numbers_show, NULL);
```

and define the event_numbers_show attributes:

```
static ssize_t event_numbers_show(struct device *dev,
        struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
    .....
    sprintf(buf, "%d\n", numbers);
    .....
}
```

then executes the sysfs entry create func in the driver init period:

```
sysfs_create_file(&dev->kobj, &dev_attr_event_numbers_show->attr);
```

If all the above succeed, than you will find the event_numbers file available in the /sys/bus/platform/devices/{YOUR_DEVICE_NAME} directory, just cat event_numbers and it will show the corresponding 'numbers'variable value.